# how to find number of repeated words in file by command?

Tags: command-line, text-processing

how to find number of repeated words in file at starting of the sentence ? 
e.g.

```
abc bdbdndnvd hddh hcjdhjc  
dgdgd ghcdggcd abc hjdhcj 
abc ghdsgcgdc cdghcgd dhgch 
hshhj hcdhchd hdjchjd
```

Output:

```
abc
```

only interested in repeated word in whole file at starting only. If that word anywhere else should not be counted.i.e. In above example `abc` is repeated twice.
Can anyone suggest me how can I do this using command ? I am using Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 5):

using `cut` and `uniq`

```
cut -d" " -f1 | sort | uniq -d
```

The `cut` command extracts the first word of each line, and `sort` in combination with `uniq -d` prints only the duplicated words.

Answer (score 4):

Using `awk`:

```
awk '{a[$1]++} END {for (i in a) if (a[i] > 1) print i}'
```

This just counts the number of times the first word in the line (`$1`) has been seen and saves it in an array. Then, just loop over all the array elements seen so far and print those which appeared multiple times.

Of course, I have gotten into a rut of looping through arrays in `END`. steeldriver notes that I don't need to:

```
awk 'a[$1]++ == 1' file
```

Comment: Based on the OP's problem statement, you could do it on-the-fly by just printing the first occurrence of each repeat `awk 'seen[$0]++ == 1' RS='[[:space:]]+' file`

Comment: @steeldriver `awk 'seen[$1]++ == 1'` then?

Comment: Ooops yes I missed the part about "at starting only"